# Simple Xpath question

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML

```
<List name="X" price="100" title="ABC">
  <Item>Value123</Item>
</List>
```

I am trying to build an XPath query where all the attributes (name , price, tittle) matches (x,100,ABC) And where the Item value is "Value123"

I just can't wrap my head around building the xpath query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List[@name='X' and @price='100' and @title='ABC' and Item='Value123']
```